# mysql procedure function returning error

Tags: mysql, function, procedure

I'm trying to create a mysql function, but i keep getting following error. What is the problem with my query?

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN INSERT INTO `order` (carID, clientID) Select car.id, client.id FROM' at line 2

My query:

```
DELIMITER //
  CREATE FUNCTION orderCreate(LicenseNumber varchar(30), Phonenumber varchar(20))
   BEGIN


   INSERT INTO `order` (carID, clientID) Select car.id, client.id FROM car, client, owns WHERE car.licensenumber = LicenseNumber AND client.phonenumber = Phonenumber AND car.id = owns.carID AND owns.clientID = client.id;


    RETURN mysql_insert_id();

  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Function's can't alter data in tables.  Procedures and packages can. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

Comment: Okay so how can  return the created order id if i change this to a procedure

Comment: Procedures have out put parameters along with result sets. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html  docs and example. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FUNTION` definition signature must have a `RETURNS` clause.
Your code did not use it.

And you can't use `mysql_insert_id()` within `MySQL` but `PHP`.
You have to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

**Function**:

```
delimiter //
drop function if exists orderCreate //

CREATE FUNCTION orderCreate( _LicenseNumber varchar(30), _Phonenumber varchar(20) )
  RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
    INSERT 
      INTO `order` ( carID, clientID )
    SELECT car.id, client.id 
      FROM car, client, owns 
     WHERE car.licensenumber = _LicenseNumber 
       AND client.phonenumber = _Phonenumber 
       AND car.id = owns.carID 
       AND owns.clientID = client.id;

    RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
END;
//
delimiter ;
```

And it would be a better practice to use different function/procedural parameter names over column names. Because unless used table name qualifiers with column names, there would arise an ambiguity in recognizing them and priority may be given to parameter names over column names.

```
select phonenumber from client;
```

Above statement may result all rows with input value `PhoneNumber` but not what you expected.

**Example**:

```
mysql> create procedure sp_so_q23838311( in deptno int )
    ->        select deptno from department
    ->        union all
    ->        select department.deptno from department;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select deptno from department;
+--------+
| deptno |
+--------+
|     10 |
|     20 |
|     30 |
|     40 |
+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> call sp_so_q23838311( 20 );
+--------+
| deptno |
+--------+
|     20 |
|     20 |
|     20 |
|     20 |
|     10 |
|     20 |
|     30 |
|     40 |
+--------+
8 rows in set (0.15 sec)
```

**Documentation on FUNCTION**:
[***CREATE FUNCTION Syntax for User-defined Functions***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function-udf.html)

> ```
> CREATE [AGGREGATE] FUNCTION function_name RETURNS {STRING|INTEGER|REAL|DECIMAL}  
> SONAME shared_library_name
> ```