# Mysql Procedure for get previous month

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have a Stored Procedure that in theory should return pervious Month, but it returns  void.

```
DROP PROCEDURE  `open_month` ;

CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE  `open_month` ( IN  `data` VARCHAR( 7 ) ) NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
BEGIN 
DECLARE DATAv VARCHAR( 10 ) DEFAULT "";

SET DATAv = CONCAT( data,  '-01' ) ;

SELECT * 
FROM incom
WHERE MONTH( DATA ) = MONTH( DATAv - INTERVAL 1 
MONTH ) ;

END
```

I'm near 24h awake and can't guess the problem. but I can advise that in query monitor of phpmyadmin, that query works if you set DATAv as user var (@).
thanks ahead!

Comment: Can you post sample values for `data` parameter and expected prev month value?

Comment: You have to declare a date in place of varchar variable

Comment: My first intention was get from month input get "2014-04" and that be treat in procedure without help from php. In pure query I got such way.  A sample in my test is the above "2014-04" to concat "2014-04-01" to get the month-1 "2014-03-1" and get the month "3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**: ***When parameter name does not match with a column name***.

Your `data` parameter seems to be in the format `Y-m` and data type is `varchar`.

So you can't get valid output but a `NULL`, on calling  like

```
month( data )
```

You need to convert `data` to valid `date` format and find its `month`.

**Example**:

```
SELECT * FROM incom
 WHERE MONTH( str_to_date( DATA, '%Y-%m' ) ) = MONTH( DATAv - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) ;
```

**Option 2**: ***When parameter name matches with a column name***:

If your table has a field with name `data`, then your procedure is not going to work, unless you use table qualifier on `data` column. This is because of ambiguity on column and parameter names to use. [Observations show that, priority will be given to parameter name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23840773/767881), when such ambiguity arises. You better change the name of the parameter a bit and use in the code. Or use table alias name to qualify the column.

**Modified Procedure**:

```
DROP PROCEDURE  if exists `open_month` ;

delimiter // 
CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` 
       PROCEDURE  `open_month` ( IN  `data` VARCHAR( 7 ) ) 
         NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE DATAv VARCHAR( 10 ) DEFAULT "";

  SET DATAv = CONCAT( data,  '-01' ) ;

  SELECT * 
    FROM incom i
   WHERE MONTH( i.DATA ) = MONTH( DATAv - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) ;

END;
//

delimiter ;
```

With such changes, your procedure should be working.

Comment: Yeah! I always set 'n' prefix for params, but this time I haven't noticed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

below query gives previous month

```
select month(now()- INTERVAL 1 month)
```

Replace now() with needed time to get respective previous month.