# I have problems with a stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I tried everything but nothing works. I have this stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS socios;
CREATE PROCEDURE socios(in nombre_u varchar(25), out socios INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO socios 
    FROM socio 
    WHERE NOMBRE_U = nombre_u; 
END
```

The condition where is not working; what can I do?

Comment: you need to tell mysql which of those numbre_u is the sproc parameter, and which is a field in your table... otherwise it'll just be executed as the equivalent of `where true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Query,

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS socios;
CREATE PROCEDURE socios ( in nombre_u varchar(25), out socios INT)
   BEGIN SELECT count(*) into socios FROM socio where NOMBRE_U=nombre_u;
END;
```

Should be changed to :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS socios;
CREATE PROCEDURE socios ( in pnombre varchar(25), out psocios INT)
   BEGIN SELECT count(*) into psocios FROM socio where NOMBRE_U=pnombre;
END;
```

Your main error was just variable naming...

Answer (score 0):

There would be a *name ambiguity* of you use same names for function parameters and column names. Instead use some other relevant names as shown in the example below:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS socios;
CREATE PROCEDURE socios(in _nombre_u varchar(25), out socios INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) into socios FROM socio where NOMBRE_U = _nombre_u; 
END;
```

One of similar answers at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23867775/767881